# How to remove the button border in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Below is my jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/xuhang1128/1wff2rqv/5/

the main code is below.

```
.design2-statusMonitor {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.design2-statusMonitor .list-group-item {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
  //border-right: 0.5px solid #CAD5E0;
  border-top: 1px solid #CAD5E0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CAD5E0;
  width: auto;
}
.design2-statusMonitor .list-group-item.selected {
  background-color: #2f749a;
}
.design2-statusMonitor .list-group-item:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.design2-statusMonitor .list-group-item:after {
  content: "";
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -6px;
  top: 43%;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
  border-top: 2px solid #CAD5E0;
  border-right: 2px solid #CAD5E0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Below is the screenshot when I clicked it. You can see that when I clicked it, the background color seems not totally fill the button, the left and right edge existed? How to remove that gap when I clicked the button like below one?
[image]
[image]

Comment: list-group-item.selected  --> list-group-item:selected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `border: none` to the:

```
.design2-statusMonitor .list-group-item.selected {
  border: none;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wff2rqv/19/)

But a better solution would be something like this:

```
.design2-statusMonitor .list-group-item.selected {
  border-top: none;
  border-right-color: #2f749a;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left-color: #2f749a;
}

.design2-statusMonitor .list-group-item.selected:hover {
  border-right-color: #c0d5e0;
  border-left-color: #c0d5e0;
}
```

Just to avoid affecting the *width*.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wff2rqv/20/)

Answer (score 0):

Set `border-color` values for `.list-group-item` elements *with the class* `.selected` to `transparent` for the following element selectors:

1. `.design2-statusMonitor .list-group-item.selected:after`
2. `.design2-statusMonitor .list-group-item.selected`

**Example:**

```
.design2-statusMonitor .list-group-item.selected:after {
    content: "";
    width: 9px;
    height: 9px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -6px;
    top: 43%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #2f749a;
    border-top: 2px solid #CAD5E0;
    border-right: 2px solid #CAD5E0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-color: transparent;
}

.design2-statusMonitor .list-group-item.selected {
    background-color: #2f749a;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wff2rqv/17/)

**Note:**

The only issue I can see with this is the detail you'll negate to visually separate two `.selected` sibling elements that happen to occur directly next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, `border: none;` did not work.

I used `border-style: hidden;` to hide the default border
and then set my own style  `border: 1px solid #cccccc;`